# One of the double dimmer is still on

Tags: electrical, switch, dimmer-switch, new-home

I have changed dimmer switch in our lounge, it’s double switch, one of them is working normally, but the other one is still on and can’t switch it off or lower the light. There is more light on this switch and neither of them is working. Is it bad switch or did I connect it wrong? Thank you.[image]![enter image description here]
[image]

Comment: What does "double switch" mean" . Two switches in one box, or two switches on either side of the room that control the same light (three-way switch)?  It's very uncommon to have a bad switch, so it's most likely a wiring problem.  Any multimeter can quickly test a light switch to see if it's bad.

Comment: Yeah, it's a simple miswiring. The better the details you can give us, the better answer we can give you.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question please?

Comment: Extra photos added

Comment: Also the other switch keep  buzzing, but not when the light is on lowest and highest level.

Answer (score 0):

You have swapped the the wires on the switch that is on all the time. There is usually 1 hot feeding the 2 switches in your case some way around you have them mixed up. A clear photo of the wires in the box and connection to the switches will give us enough info to help straighten this out.  Or a detailed description of the wires and what cables they come from and where they go.

Comment: Some additional pictures added. Thank you for your answers..

Comment: also the other switch keep  buzzing, but not when the light is on lowest and highest level.